# mod_rewrite issues with something that used to work

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a virtual private server that was borked over the weekend, and has been upgraded.  Sometime between now and then, some changes have been made that have impacted a mod_rewrite call, but I'm not sure which.

In any event, I have a folder with a PHP script that emulates a CAS server.  The system used to work fine and dandy until today. Now, instead of the mod_rewrite directives providing commands via rewrite to the index.php file, Apache goes '404' and sends me up a directory to Wordpress's 404 handler.

This is the htaccess code that used to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA, L]
```

The URL variables appeared in CAS-appropriate commands (like cas/login, cas/logout), but are now generating 404s.

There may have been Apache tweaking; do I need to add any commands to the htaccess (like Options Indexes) or something to make Apache listen to the rewrite commands?

Oddly, the force-https command seems to work.